# Giphy get gifs from user api in htmlcode?

Tags: html, api, embed, giphy, giphy-api

I am a Giphy Creator and i want to use the Giphy API in an embed HTML code ..

I was only successful getting a random GIF from Search

here is the code .. if any one could help it would be amazing :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Random GIF Player</title>
    <style>
      /* Full page background */
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      /* Centered GIF element */
      #gif {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- GIF element -->
    <img id="gif" src="" />

    <!-- JavaScript to load a random GIF from Giphy -->
    <script>
      // API endpoint for Giphy random GIFs from a specific user
      var endpoint =
        "https://api.giphy.com/v1/users/mahmood/gifs?api_key=**API KEY HERE**&rating=G";

      // Set the GIF source to a random GIF from the specified user on Giphy
      function setRandomGif() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", endpoint);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data;
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
            var gif = document.getElementById("gif");
            gif.src = data[randomIndex].images.original.url;
          }
        };
        xhr.send();
      }

      // Load a random GIF when the page loads
      setRandomGif();

      // Load a new random GIF when the user clicks on the GIF
      var gif = document.getElementById("gif");
      gif.addEventListener("click", setRandomGif);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

so here the code searches for random image /mahmoud

i wrote it using chat gpt :S

what i want is that it plays a random image from my Giphy account here :

https://giphy.com/user

`https://api.giphy.com/v1/users/{username}/gifs?api_key={api_key}&rating=G`
this didnt work .. i got a black page nothing

```
https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=***************&q=user:mahmood&limit=100&rating=G
```

this also blank .. nothing happened

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.